# Nested loops: permuting an n-dimensional array represented by a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, loops

I have an `n`-dimensional array `T` where each dimension has the same length `L`. This array is represented by a 1D vector `v` (which can be seen as a "reshaped" version of `T`, thus the length of `v` is `L^n`).

The following example shows how `v` is indexed according to the indices of `T` (where `n = 3` and `L = 4`):

[image]

(e.g. `T(0,3,2) = v[14]`)

What I would like to do is to create a vector `u` that represents an `n`-dimensional array `S` where `S` is obtained by permuting/rotating `T` by 1, i.e.

`T(i1,i2,...,in) = S(i2,i3,...,in,i1)` for any `(i1,i2,...,in)`.

(When `T` is a matrix, `S` corresponds to the transpose of `T`).

**Update:**

The following code may better explain my question:

```
void permute(vector<double> &output, const vector<double> &v, int L)
{
    int n = log(v.size())/log(L);

    // Suppose that we have a function doing this
    narray T = get_narray_from_vector(v, L);

    // Get the permutation of T
    narray S(T.size());
    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < L; i1++){
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < L; i2++){
            ...
            for(int in = 0; in < L; in++){
                S(i2,i3,...,in,i1) = T(i1,i2,...,in);
            }
        }
    }

    // get vector from narray
    output.resize(v.size());
    int idx = 0;   
    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < L; i1++){
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < L; i2++){
            ...
            for(int in = 0; in < L; in++){
                output[idx] = S(i1,i2,...,in);
                idx++;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

In practice, however, I think it is much better working directly with vectors. Thus, I would do something like this:

```
void permute(vector<double> &output, const vector<double> &v, int L)
{
    int n = log(v.size())/log(L);
    output.resize(v.size());

    // Get the permutation
    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < L; i1++){
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < L; i2++){
            ...
            for(int in = 0; in < L; in++){
                output[i2*pow(L, n-1) + i3*pow(L, n-2) + ... + in*L + i1] = v[i1*pow(L, n-1) + i2*pow(L, n-2) + ... + i_{n-1}*L + in];
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The difficulty here is the nested loop, because `n` is a parameter.

Any ideas how to do that?
Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: Your question is not really clear.   What have you attempted?  Assuming `i1`, `i2`, etc represent "columns", you want to remove the first column, shuffle all the other columns by one, and then add the (removed) first column as the last?   (Note:  in context of multi-dimensional arrays, the word "transpose" has a particular meaning, which seems different to what you are using that word for).

Comment: Do you need to store T in a vector in this way? My first inclination would be to store it as an "array of arrays" extended to n dimensions, and then what (I think) you are asking for would only require shifting the top level array by one index

Comment: Also, it seems like in your example each dimension has length 4 (0, 1, 2, 3) while you say that L=3

Comment: totally off topic: @Nic vectors of vectors and arrays of arrays have potentially significant performance penalties due to poor spacial locality.

Comment: @user4581301 That is true in many (probably most) cases, but it depends on what is being done with the matrix. For example, if this is the only operation that needs to be implemented you could save orders of magnitude of memory accesses by simply shifting an array of pointers rather than moving all of the data in the entire matrix

Comment: @Peter Please see the update.

Comment: @Nic Yes I need to store T in a vector (at least in my current code. I'll think about using a tensor library later). And yes, thanks for pointing out the typo, `L=4` indeed. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that does not require `n` nested for loops.

First, I have some old code which decomposes numbers into an `L`-based number system.

```
std::vector<int>
num2base(const int value,
         const unsigned int base){

  // Represents an input int VALUE in a new BASE-based number system                                                                                                    
  // n = a0*b^0 + a1*b^1 + ...                                                                                                                                          

  std::vector<int> base_representation;
  unsigned int num_digs = (unsigned int) (floor(log(value)/log(base))+1);
  base_representation.resize(num_digs);

  for (unsigned int i_dig = 0; i_dig < num_digs; i_dig++){
    base_representation[i_dig] =
      ((value % (int) pow(base,i_dig+1)) - (value % (int) pow(base, i_dig))) /
      (int) pow(base, i_dig);
  }

  return base_representation;
}
```

In other words, it's a way to convert your single value index `idx` to your `i1` to `in` `n`-tuple index.

```
idx = i1*L^0 + i2*L^1 + ... in*L^(n-1)
```

Here's the code to go the other way

```
int
base2num(const std::vector<int> base_representation,
         const unsigned int base){

  unsigned int digit_val = 1;

  int value = 0;

  for (unsigned int digit = 0; digit < base_representation.size(); digit++){
    value += base_representation[digit]*digit_val;
    digit_val *= base;
  }

  return value;
}
```

Once you have the `std::vector<int>` representing your `n`-tuple index, it's easy to permute it.

```
void
permute_once(std::vector<int> &base_representation){

  std::vector<int>::iterator pbr = base_representation.begin();
  int tmp = *pbr;
  base_representation.erase(pbr);
  base_representation.push_back(tmp);

  return;
}
```

So, to generate the new `n`-dimensional array `S`

1. Go through every index `idxS` of `S`.
2. Convert `idxS` to a `n`-tuple (`iS1`, `iS2`, ..., `iSn`)
3. Find the associated entry in `T` and its `n`-tuple (`iT1`, `iT2`, ..., `iTn`)
4. Convert it to a single index `idxT`.
5. `u[idxS] = v[idxT];`

Comment: Thanks. That's a way to do, too.